# Tensorflow training loss has macro similarites over different runs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have CNN that I'm training on an image set that is stored in a `tfrecord`. The relevant code is below:

```
def parse_function(proto):
    ....

    train_path = "...."
    seed = random.randint(0, int(2**32 - 1))
    buffer_size = 300

    tf.set_random_seed(seed)
    train_set = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(train_path)
    train_set = train_set.map(parse_function)
    train_set = train_set.shuffle(buffer_size=buffer_size, seed=seed)
    train_set = train_set.batch(batch_size)
    train_set = train_set.repeat()

    iterator = train_set.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    model = build_mode(next_element)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for i in range(iters):
            sess.run(model.train_op)
```

The loss function over many runs with different random seeds has many macro similarities (indicated by arrows in the bellow image)

[image: Loss value vs iteration with macro similarities]

There are 4 separate runs being trained here. Note that this is zoomed in a bit to highlight the similarities, this is just the first 1000 iterations. These similarities show up about every 1000 iterations. If I change the batch size the same thing seems to happen just shifted.

To me this points to the dataset not being shuffled at all. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is related to the batch size and buffer size used. The `buffer_size` parameter in `shuffle` represents the number of elements from the dataset that are being sampled from at any given time by the subsequent `batch` function. Thus, if `buffer_size` is not sufficiently large (in particular when compared to the `batch_size`), there may not be adequate randomization when sampling the dataset.

I like to think of `buffer_size` as a moving window across your dataset, where the randomization happens within the window (it is more nuanced than this, but it's the image I like to visualize). So if your window size is very small compared to the size of the dataset, generally, you won't be randomizing across a large portion of the dataset at any given time, leading to periodic correlations between batches across iterations.

Try increasing `buffer_size` from `300` to a number of data points that you can comfortably fit in memory. So for example, if you are dealing with `n` dimensional float data, and you have `500MB` to spare for data preprocessing, then you can fit approximately `500MB/(n*64B)` in memory for the shuffle (approximately `80000` for `n=100`). This should enhance the extent of randomization when creating batches.

Comment: That doesn't seem to help. It does change the shape from the original training loss spikes a bit, but it is still periodic with roughly the same peeks. Adding `train_set.skip(n)`, changed the shape much more dramatically (as my data is stored like a video sequence), however it is still periodic.

Comment: Could it be an artifact of the `AdamOptimizer`?

Comment: How large is your dataset, and what value did you use for `buffer_size`? I'm not sure if it's the `AdamOptimizer` in isolation, as it's supposed to smooth gradient noise, but won't necessarily remove periodic effects due to periodicity in sampling.

Comment: There was an unrelated bug in my code. After fixing that, you suggestion worked!